# Pytest raise Error and return value from Mock

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have the the following method in a `RedisDriver` class:

```
def get(self, key):
    key_str = str(key)
    try:
        master = self.connection.master_for(self.service)
        value = master.get(key_str)
    except RedisError as err:
        error_str = "Error while retrieving value from redis : " + str(err)
        return {"success": False, "error": error_str}
```

I want to check is the error message is correct:

I tried the following:

```
@mock.patch("code.redis_driver.redis_sentinel")
@mock.patch("code.redis_driver.RedisDriver.get", side_effect=RedisError)
def test_redis_driver_delete(mocked_sentinel, mock_redis_sentinel):
    mocked_master = mock.Mock()
    mock_redis_sentinel.master_for.return_value = mocked_master
    redis_driver = RedisDriver(mock_redis_sentinel)
    result = redis_driver.get("test")
    assert result == {"success": False, "error": "test"}
```

This does not work since an exception is raised:

```
E               redis.exceptions.RedisError
```

Since this does not work I try the following:

```
@mock.patch("code.redis_driver.redis_sentinel")
@mock.patch("code.redis_driver.RedisDriver.get", side_effect=RedisError)
def test_redis_driver_delete(mocked_sentinel, mock_redis_sentinel):
    mocked_master = mock.Mock()
    mock_redis_sentinel.master_for.return_value = mocked_master
    redis_driver = RedisDriver(mock_redis_sentinel)
    with pytest.raises(RedisError) as exception:
        result = redis_driver.get("test")
        assert result == {"success": False, "error": str(exception)}
```

This always passes, whatever I set `result` to. How can I catch the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by mocking the whole class and use `side_effect` on the get method:

```
@mock.patch("code.redis_driver.RedisDriver")
def test_redis_driver_delete(mock_redis_sentinel):
    mocked_master = mock.Mock()
    mocked_master.get.side_effect = RedisError("error")
    mock_redis_sentinel.master_for.return_value = mocked_master
    redis_driver = RedisDriver(mock_redis_sentinel)
    result = redis_driver.get("test")
    assert result == {"success": False, "error": "Error while retrieving value from redis : error"}
```